# Is it necessary to clean the Linux kernel source tree after each bisection step?

Tags: linux, git, linux-kernel

When bisecting the Linux kernel source tree between two relatively distant
commits, the first few bisection steps usually change a great deal of the
kernel source, so whether `make distclean` is run or not, won't make a big
difference. However, as the bisection scope gets narrower, fewer source files
are changed at each step, so cleaning the source tree will remove a lot of
`*.o` files that don't need to be rebuilt.

Since `make` infers the object files that need to be rebuilt by comparing their
last modification time to that of their associated source files, I would assume
that it is not necessary to clean the tree after each bisection step, but I do
it anyway as a precaution after I ran into a situation where a lengthy
bisection process got me eventually into a "bad" commit that has nothing to do
with the bug in question.

To make it concrete, here are the steps I used in the first bisection attempt
(which got me into the wrong commit):

```sh
cp /boot/config-`uname -r` .config
make oldconfig
make && sudo make modules_install && sudo make install
# reboot
# Then I repeat the following steps until the bisection ends.
# test the kernel
git bisect {good,bad}
make && sudo make modules_install && sudo make install
# reboot
```

I bisected again using the following procedure, and was able to successfully
reach the faulty commit:

```sh
make distclean
cp /boot/config-`uname -r` .config
make oldconfig
make && sudo make modules_install && sudo make install
# reboot
# test the kernel
git bisect {good,bad}
# Then I repeat the steps above until the bisection ends.
```

Since I'm not very knowledgable of the internals of the kenrel build system, it
would be great if someone could point me at some way by which I could avoid
cleaning and rebuilding the entire kernel after each bisection step, since that
would save me a lot of build time, and will shorten the bisection process
considerably.

Answer (score 3):

From
[the man](http://linux.die.net/man/1/make)

> The make program uses the makefile data base and the last-modification times
> of the files to decide which of the files need to be updated.

and a quick experiment

```
$ stat -c%y bar.txt
2013-05-11 22:58:46.499826200 -0500

$ git checkout HEAD~1
HEAD is now at e7b9f1c... first

$ stat -c%y bar.txt
2013-05-11 22:58:52.583836900 -0500
```

As you can see, performing a `checkout` changes the modification time of the
file, and in turn would force it to be recompiled with `make`. So the answer
is no, it is not necessary to clean the tree because the necessary file will be
recompiled.

Comment: Thanks Steven for the answer. I know that `make` checks the modification time, and also that `git checkout` changes it. But my question was more about whether the kernel build system doesn't make things as straightforward, because I encounter different bisection results depending on whether I run `make distclean` or not after each step.

Comment: I updated the question with more explicit info about the issue I encountered during bisection, as well as the exact commands I used. I hope this will help.